# How to exclude table cells paragraphs from getParagraphs() in DocumentApp, apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, paragraph

I need to get all the paragraphs from a google document. For that, I am using `body.getParagraphs()`.
The problem is, in any document, if any table exists, the `body.getParagraphs()` method takes all the table cells as a paragraph and returns as a paragraph. Now what I want is to get all the paragraphs only, from a document and exclude the table and table cells from that. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the paragraphs except for the table cell using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about checking the element type? When this is reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document.

```
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  
  const res = paragraphs.filter(p => p.getParent().getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_CELL);
  
  // do something

}
```

- In this sample script, the values of `paragraphs` include the paragraphs of table cell.
- By filtering the element type, `res` can have only the paragraphs except for the table cell.

#### References:

- [getParent() of Class Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getparent)
- [getType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#getType())